# Is it possible to tell Visual Studio to copy project local 3rdparty includes from a remote Linux machine to Windows InstalliSense cache?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, cross-platform

I have a Visual Studio MSBuild Linux project and I have 3rdparty libraries installed by vcpkg (in manifest mode) into vcpkg_installed subdirectory in a project directory on a remote machine. I want includes from these libraries to be available to IntelliSense. Currently the system includes are copied and cached locally on Windows. I assume if I use vcpkg system-wide, I could set the libraries install directory for remote copy in Remote Headers IntelliSense Manager. But what to do with project-specific 3rdparty headers installed locally in a project folder?